# Couldn't see the other data tables in rdlc

Tags: winforms, datatable, rdlc

I already created one of this kind of report in rdlc but now I couldn't do it anymore, I wonder why.

1st, I created a dataset with 3 data tables
[image]

2nd I created a Tabular report and added the dataset, I was prompted to add a single dataset with one data table, I chose RetrieveCandidates data table
[image]

after that, I can create a data grid/table for the candidate then I added a textbox for the logged administrator. Unfortunately, I couldn't see the other data tables. i couldn't remember how I managed to add those three data tables before.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I was looking at the wrong pane. I should be using the Report Data Pane not the Data Source

Answer (score 0):

A tablix can only be associated with a DataSet, for that reason you do not see all the fields. The only solution is to create a DataSet which has all the fields you need or create a subreport with data having another DataSet.